# How to add y-axis directional labels in ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to replicate something like the plot image below in ggplot() with upper and lower directional labels on the y-axis (labels highlighted for clarity). I would like to use something like geom_label() or geom_text(), but the required x locations are outside of the range of plot values (e.g. x=-10) so that does not work. I see that it can be done using tick labels with custom breaks, but I am already using breaks to set ticks, and I would like these to display more like the axis label, not a tick mark.

[image: Example plot]

Comment: One can use e.g. `coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')` to enable drawing outside the plot region.

Comment: Yes, perfect, thanks. I actually ended up customized break labels as I liked the results better, but turning off clipping did allow me to place labels where I wanted them.